# How to implement StartActivityForResult in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, startactivityforresult

I am trying to use an startActivityForResult in my RecyclerView and don't know how... tried this way and i get a NullPointExeption from Activity, is there any way to solve it.

**This is Activity:**

```
    RecyclerView recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.todo_Recyclerview);
    Todo_Adapter adapter=new Todo_Adapter(this,Todo_DataGenerator.getData(this));
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

TextView title=findViewById(R.id.todo_txt_Titleitem);
TextView content=findViewById(R.id.todo_txt_Contentitem);


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    if (requestCode== Request &&
            resultCode==RESULT_OK &&
            data !=null){

        String Title=data.getStringExtra(Todo_saveActivity.Todo_Title);
        String Content=data.getStringExtra(Todo_saveActivity.Todo_Content);

        title.setText(Title);
        content.setText(Content);
```

**This is Adapter:**

```
public class Todo_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Todo_Adapter.Todo_itemViewHolder> {
public static final int Request = 1002;

private Context context;
private List<Todo_SampleClass> Notes;



public Todo_Adapter(Context context, List<Todo_SampleClass> Notes) {

    this.context = context;
    this.Notes = Notes;

}

@Override
public Todo_itemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.todo_rv_item, parent, false);
    return new Todo_itemViewHolder(view);

}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Todo_itemViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bindNotes(Notes.get(position));
    holder.Add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(context, Todo_saveActivity.class);
            ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(intent,Request);

        }
    });

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return Notes.size();
}

public class Todo_itemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView Title;
    private TextView Content;
    private ImageButton edit;
    private ImageButton remove;
    private Button Add;

    public Todo_itemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        Title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.todo_txt_Titleitem);
        Content = itemView.findViewById(R.id.todo_txt_Contentitem);
        edit = itemView.findViewById(R.id.todo_btn_edit);
        remove = itemView.findViewById(R.id.todo_btn_remove);
        Add = itemView.findViewById(R.id.todo_btn_add);

    }


    public void bindNotes(Todo_SampleClass Notes) {
        Title.setText(Notes.getTitle());
        Content.setText(Notes.getContent());
        edit.setImageDrawable(Notes.getImgbtn_edit());

        remove.setImageDrawable(Notes.getImgbtn_remove());
    }

    }

}
```

**This is second Activity that i am trying to go:**

```
public class Todo_saveActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


public static final String Todo_Title ="result";
public static final String Todo_Content="content";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_todo_save);


    final EditText Title=findViewById(R.id.todo_name);
   final EditText Content=findViewById(R.id.todo_family);
```

**This is logcat:**

```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.expert2.expert2/com.example.expert2.expert2.rv_Todo.Todo_rv}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:117)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:149)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:29)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:54)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:202)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:183)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:519)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:190)
                  at com.example.expert2.expert2.rv_Todo.Todo_rv.<init>(Todo_rv.java:29)
                  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
```

Thanks.------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: In your adapter, where are you getting the variable `context` from?

Answer (score 7):

When looking at this code:

```
public static final int Request = 1002;

 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Todo_itemViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bindNotes(Notes.get(position));
    holder.Add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(context, Todo_saveActivity.class);
            ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(intent,Request);

        }
    });

}
```

It looks to me like ((Activity) context) seems to be the problem. You are trying to call startActivityForResult(...) with an Activity object that is null. Depending on whether your RecyclerView is in an Activity or Fragment, make sure that you are setting `context` equal to a valid instance of your parent Activity's context, like:

```
Context context = getContext(); //if in fragment
Context context = (Context)this; //if in parent activity
```

and then later on you should be able to call

```
((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(intent,Request);
```

without any issues.

Comment: Thanks...parent Activity u mean first activity? my RecyclerView is activity but is not first...where exactly i should add?

Comment: If you are using fragments, the parent activity is the activity that the fragment lives inside of.

Answer (score 3):

If you're open to the idea of using a callback to do this, rather than doing it directly in your activity...

Create an interface like this:

```
public interface OnBindCallback {
    void onViewBound(Todo_itemViewHolder viewHolder, int position);
}
```

Then, in your adapter:

```
public OnBindCallback onBind;

@Override public void onBindViewHolder(Todo_itemViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (onBind != null) {
        onBind.onViewBound(holder, position);
    }
}
```

And finally, in your activity:

```
adapter.onBind = (viewHolder, position) -> {
    viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(YourActivityName.this, Todo_saveActivity.class);
            YourActivityName.this.startActivityForResult(intent, 1002);
        }
    });
};
```